# Gluten free baked good coming out bitter

Tags: baking, gluten-free

I am trying to bake gluten free and i find that my baked goods come out bitter. I am using oat flour and rice flour, can the bitterness be from that, what can i do to correct this?
What is a good gluten free flour other then oat?

Thank you

Comment: It's all baked goods, not just one recipe? Are the flours the only things in common between them all? Have you tried tasting the flours independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those ingredients are not bitter unless they are rancid. You may be using too much baking soda?

A basic gluten free flour is usually a combination of white rice flour, brown rice flour, sweet rice flour, tapioca starch and xanthan or guar gum. From there it can go into buckwheat, bean flours, quinoa, etc. The gums give resilience and elasticity to the dough (along with the tapioca and sweet rice flour) and replace the action of the gluten which creates a structure for baked goods to rise.

There's lots of gluten free flour recipes that come up with a Google search. It's sometimes easier to start with those than trying to create one from scratch.

Oats BTW, are not strictly gluten free because of cross contamination when growing or processing. The package should state that they are gluten free.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using too much baking powder (gluten free) and / or cream of tarter can give an oddly bitter aftertaste to baked goods.